# Data binding List of custom items

Tags: android, android-databinding

How do I bind a List of custom items to a ListView or a RecyclerView? Using only Android **DEFAULT** DataBinding (no external library)

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="java.util.List"/>
        <variable name="listOfString" type="List&lt;String>"/>
    </data>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:?????="@{listOfString}/>  <!--Like we have ItemsSource in WPF-->

</layout>
```

I came from WPF background, in which there is a ItemTemplate option. Using ItemTemplate you can map data to your view purely through XML. Something like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserCollection}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <!--Populate template with each user data-->
    <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel>
        <!--Bind to user.Name-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" />
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I am reading the android data binding guide, but i thought this is a good question to be found on SO, so i brought it up

Comment: @nmtuan : Can you please add more details about what you actually want to do using databinding?

Comment: @AndiGeeky i just want the ListView or RecyclerView to show the collection of items, could be anything, like "class Message { String content }"

Comment: like in WPF or Window forms you have DataSource or ItemsSource on Collection-Type-Controls, i cant find a similar property like this on android where i could 'bind to'

Comment: @nmtuan : Are you talking about custom design or custom data?

Comment: I am following this guide 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If this can help someone, sounds to me that what you are looking for are Binding adadpters from DataBinding feature.

More info can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

This will allow you to define custom property that can be used inside xml and pass a list of items that you need.

```
@BindingAdapter("nameOfProperty")
public static void loadImage(ListView listView, List listOfString) {
  // do the actual logic here
}
```

This can then be used in xml like `app:nameOfPropery="@{listOfString}"`

Answer (score -1):

Check out this library: https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter.

This library allow to bind ObservableList of custom Objects to RecyclerView.

Comment: He is not looking for a library

Comment: @Trinity Of course, better to reinvent the wheel (again and again). You always can look at the source code and find interesting parts.